# Java fix regex in code

Tags: java, regex

I need to print **@OPOK**, but in the following code:

```
String s = "\"MSG1\":\"00\",\"MSG2\":\"@OPOK\",\"MSG3\":\"XXXXXX\"}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\"MSG2\":\"(.+)\".*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("Match not found");
}
```

I get **@OPOK","MSG3":"XXXXXX** instead, how do I fix my pattern ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make your `.+` part *reluctant*. By default it's greedy - it'll match as much as it can without preventing the pattern from matching. You want it to match as *little* as it can, like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\"MSG2\":\"(.+?)\".*");
```

The `?` is what makes it reluctant. See the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation for more details.

Or of course you could just match against "any character other than a double quote" which is what Brian's approach will do. Both will work equally well as far as I'm aware; there may well be *performance* differences between them (I'd expect Brian's to perform better to be honest) but if performance is important to you you should test both approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"MSG2\":\"([^\"]+)\"");
```

For the capture group you are interested in, this will match any character except a double quote.  Since the group is surrounded by double quotes, this should prevent it from going "too far" in the match.

*Edited to add*: As @bmorris591 suggested in the comments, you can add an extra `+` (as shown below) to make the quantifier [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).  This may help improve performance in cases where the matcher fails to find a match.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"MSG2\":\"([^\"]++)\"");
```

Comment: +1 but only `"\"MSG2\":\"([^\"]+)\""` is enough. No need to go for `.*` before and after.

Comment: You can make the `[^"]` possessive with a second plus, `[^"]++` - this will make the matcher a little (and maybe a lot) faster when parsing non-matching strings.

Comment: @anubhava Good point.  I've edited my post to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: @bmorris591 Thanks for the suggestion.  Would this have an impact even if there are not any other wildcards in the expression?  In this case, I'm thinking the regex engine would not do any backtracking, so there would be no need to add the possessive quantifier (although I suppose it wouldn't hurt either).

Comment: You have a greedy matcher so it will grab everything it can and then backtrack if there is not a match - in a situation where the String does not match the pattern this will be quite costly.